# How to track all successful & unsuccessful connections an application makes?

Tags: windows, tcpip

I am running Windows 7. How can I track and record all URLs a specific process is attempting to connect to, and report successes or failures (and a timestamp for each try)?  FAIL means the process received no response or data from its target.

e.g.:

```
01:00:00 chrome.exe http://dl.google.com/update:80 SUCCESS

01:00:01 chrome.exe http://www.google.com/login:80 FAIL

01:00:02 chrome.exe http://www.google.com/:80 SUCCESS
```

Something along those lines?

Comment: How do you define success and failure? It's might be possible to detect attempts that were, say, blocked by a firewall, but extremely difficult to figure out whether a website logon attempt failed.

Comment: I would say FAIL means the process received no response or data from its target.

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is an amazing free tool that lets you see and debug web based issues.  This tool will do exactly what you are asking for and far more.  It can log one application, or an entire computers web requests, results, time for each request, and much, much more.